# Ownership of a collectively created object

Tags: licensing, ownership

Imagine an art event, where participants contribute to the creation of a piece of art. For the sake of argument, imagine there is a raw block of stone in an exhibition hall and each visitor will get to make one strike with a hammer in order to form it. The result is a statue, or kind of, at least.

Now does the organizer of the event has the right to sell the resulting "product" and solely benefit from the profit? Or do the participants of the event need to sign some kind of a waiver in order for the organizer to do so?

Note: the organizer does not claim creation rights nor makes a secret as to how the object was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The organiser owns the stone and can do what they want with it, including profiting from any sale.

Each participant jointly owns the copyright in the artistic work and jointly control how and if any copies or derivatives (like photographs) of the work might be made or dealt with.